# Trying to write a simple computed column expression (IF Statement)

Tags: calculated-columns, computed-field

I have a column in my table called "BanquetPrize" and another column called "PrizeWinner."  If the "BanquetPrize" field is `NOT NULL`, I'd like the "PrizeWinner" field to auto-fill with "YES," and if it `IS NULL`, it should be "NO."  (Persisted)

I'm really new to SQL and coming from DBF tables where the expression would have been:

```
IF(IsNotBlank(BanquetPrize), "YES", "NO")
```

But I can't figure out how to write it in SQL.  What I've tried:

```
(IIF [BanquetPrize]isnotnull then 'YES' else 'NO' end)
-- and also  --
(case when [BanquetPrize]isnotnull then 'YES' else 'NO' end)
```

Obviously the syntax was wrong with both of these, so I was hoping someone could educate me on the correct way to write it?

Answer (score 0):

In SQL You want to use `IS NULL` as shown in the following code

```
CASE [BanquetPrize]
 WHEN IS NULL THEN 'NO'
 ELSE 'YES'
END
```

You can also do something like the following to give the return column a name, in this case I am giving it a name same as column which is **BanquetPrize**

```
CASE [BanquetPrize]
 WHEN IS NULL THEN 'NO'
 ELSE 'YES'
END AS 'BanquetPrize'
```

Additional Example when using CASE in `ORDER BY` Clause

```
SELECT CustomerName, City, Country
FROM Customers
ORDER BY
(CASE
    WHEN City IS NULL THEN Country
    ELSE City
END);
```

Read more about SQL `CASE` statement and using `IS NULL` here https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.   (Bear with me a bit because I am such a newbie.)  In your first example, I understand the syntax, but how is all of that written on one line?  There isn't room in the "formula" field of the computed column to enter 4 lines like you have shown?  Does it all just run together as a single sentence?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CASE or IIF

CASE

```
SELECT BanquetPrize, CASE WHEN BanquetPrize IS NOT NULL THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END as PrizeWinner
FROM t1;
```

IIF

```
SELECT BanquetPrize, IIF(BanquetPrize iS NOT NULL,'YES','NO') as PrizeWinner
FROM t1;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c4b8a23a395dc62a569eecbe7787dd70)

Comment: I must be doing something wrong.  I copied your expression except that I changed the table name of "t1" to the actual table name of FEES, and it wouldn't all fit in the space allotted for a formula.                                  

This is what I tried to input:
SELECT BanquetPrize, IIF(BanquetPrize iS NOT NULL,'YES','NO') as PrizeWinner
FROM fees;

And this is all it would take:
SELECT BanquetPrize, IIF(BanquetPrize iS NOT NULL,'YES','NO') as PrizeWinner

Comment: "...space allotted for a formula..." What are you using on this?